# Accessing matrix data from text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
AA=x(1:3,:);
fName = 'data510_1125.txt';         
fid = fopen(fName,'w');
[r,c]=size(AA);
x=repmat('%d\t',1,(c-1));
fprintf(fid,[x,'%d\n'],AA');
```

x is a 3*200000 matrix.This may vary.I write this matrix to a text file using the above code. Have I made any mistake in storing the matrix to text file? If so, tell me my error.I hope it is right.

**Now I want to access this matrix data from that text file and assign it to a variable.** **How do i do it?**

*(Note: All the data in the matrix are float)*

Comment: So do you want to read in the matrix from file?

Comment: yes i need it in the same matrix form

Comment: You should really try looking for similar questions.  I've found a duplicate.

Comment: i looked up...some told to use fscan. But fscan reads the data as a single column vector.(i.e) a matrix of 2*6, is read as 12*1

Comment: .... please look at the duplicate.

Comment: can you give me the link to the duplicate

Comment: It's at the top of your post?  How can you not see the text **This question already has an answer here:
how to read a matrix from a text file in matlab 4 answers**?